# ASP.NET messed project restoration

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I have developed a asp.net application using Visual Studio 2008 and it was working fine. After couple of weeks when I opening the project I noticed the designer files are not nested like "aspx, aspx.cs, designer.cs ..instead all the designer files were on root level.

Tried to play around to make it nested properly and messed the project. Can anyone please guide how to create new project and add the existing project files to make it straight.

Comment: There is an option at the top of the solution explorer called "Nest Related Files", have you tried checking this?

Comment: yep already did that but its not working..the VS 2008 ide suxs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to the directory of your project and find the file with extention **.suo** and with the same name of your project and delete it (is hidden).

Then open your poject again.

Comment: Classic Atristos you saved my #$#$# :) thank you so much the .suo in disguise was the culprit :).